# How do I automate the deployment of an SSRS 2008R2 server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, deployment, automation, ssrs

I’m trying to write an automated deployment script for SSRS, and I can’t seem to find any information on how to automate the process of configuring the server after a Files-Only installation.  I have a script to install the reports, but I can’t figure out how to automate the steps in the Reporting Services Configuration manager.

Specifically:  How do I set up the Web Service URL, database and report manager URL using a script?

Update: I'm trying to automate this process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting services exposes a WMI interface that can be scripted via powershell or other scripting provider I believe there is also a way to achieve some of this via the commandline and rsconfig.exe

The Report Server WMI provider exposes classes, properties, and methods that allow you to configure all aspects of a Reporting Services installation including specifying service accounts, configuring virtual directories, creating and configuring the report server database, or configuring a report server for e-mail delivery.

For more information:

Rsconfig,exe:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162837.aspx

Installing Reporting Services from the Command Prompt:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144272(SQL.90).aspx

Reporting Services WMI Provider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152836(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I've managed to get this working through the WMI tools, so I just need to script it now!

Comment: Thats awesome you should post your scripts

Comment: Yes, he really should have. Here I am, more than 5 years later, looking for the same information ...